# Bot is not restarting after the exit process

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I have these three lines of code for my restart command. However, when I run the command, the bot goes down and never comes back up. I am not entirely sure why the bot is not restarting on its own; or is that possible with this code?

Nodemon: `v^2.0.4`
Discord.JS: `v12.2.0`

```js
const { token } = require("./config.json");
// Other Codes

  if (message.author.id !== '422103069808132106') return;
  await message.channel.send("Restarting")
  process.exit().then(() => client.login(token))
```

Comment: When you call `process.exit()` your code stops running, so it can't log itself back into Discord.

Comment: So is there a way that once the code stops running, it'll come back up? using the `client.login`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is possible to do something like this by using `child_process`. You can add it by running `npm i child_process` then import it like this: `const cp = require('child_process');`.

The code for restart would then look something like this:

```
await message.channel.send("Restarting")
const child = cp.spawn('node', ['<YourScriptFileNameHere>'], { detached: true })
child.unref()
process.exit()
```

This will create another process that will run your script again, and detach it from the current process. Now when you run `process.exit()` the current process exits but another one will be running the bot in the background.

If you usually run something like `node index.js` to start the bot in a console, you won't be able see any output once you run the first restart command. If you look in Task Manager you could find the process running the bot by searching for `Node.js: Server-side Javascript`. If you want to stop the bot you would have to end this task manually.

I haven't noticed any memory leaks doing this myself, but that could be a concern if you are running the restart command often.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, when I try to run the command it says `[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart` as I am using nodemon. But is there a way that if I run the command it'll automatically restart?